# pdfMake table header not repeated on page break

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

Can I force somehow the table header repeating on each page in pdfMake, when I have a big table, that only fits on multiple pages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By setting the `headerRows`, it will repeat automatically.

Like

```
table: {
    headerRows: 1,
    body: [
        ...
    ]
}
```